# Solving Linear Modular System with different Moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Suppose we had a list of modular expressions as follows:

$$ y_0 \equiv s_0 \mod r_0 $$

$$ y_0 \equiv s_1 \mod r_0-1 $$

$$ y_0 \equiv s_2 \mod r_0-2 $$

$$ y_0 \equiv s_3 \mod r_0-3 $$

$$ y_0 \equiv s_n \mod r_0-n $$

We could find the modular equation for any $n$. Is there a way to solve for $y_0$?

**update** That is to say, for every equation we would know the value of $s_n$ and $r_0$, but $y_0$ is unknown.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: Thanks!! That works.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem applies only when the moduli are pairwise coprime. If $r_0$ is even, so is $r_0-2$. If $r_0$ is odd, both $r_0-1$ and $r_0-3$ are even.